# Azure Automation watcher task pass data to action task

Tags: powershell, azure, automation

I have configured a watcher task to monitor a group in AD. If a new user is found, select the samaccountname and convert to JSON, then send to the action  task using `Invoke-AutomationWatcherAction -Data $DataOut` where $DataOut looks like:

```
[
    {
        "SamAccountName":  "UserA"
    },
    {
        "SamAccountName":  "UserB"
    }
]
```

But when it is passed to the Action task it appears as:

```
[
    {
       "UserA"
    },
    {
       "UserB"
    }
]
```

I have verified that the object is as expected before being set to $DataOut and also on the Action task you can look at *input* but the headers are missing there as well..l

Anyone have experience passing objects from Azure Automation watcher tasks to  action tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Do you Convert-FromJson on the event object in the Action Task as well?

This works for me on a file watcher Action task (examples in MSDN documentation).

```
# File Movement

# $EVENTDATA is passed in as a parameter to the Action runbook.
$event = $EVENTDATA | Select EventProperties
$data = $event.EventProperties.Data | ConvertFrom-Json
$outputPath = $data.FileName
$outputFile = Split-Path $outputPath -Leaf

Write-Output $data 
Write-Output $outputFile
```